# MySQL, get date where row sum = 3

Tags: sql, mariadb-10.3

I want to find the 3rd available appointment from a list of appointments.

MySql database has rows with RotaType, Date and UnusedSlots as columns

I want to do something like

```
 $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM `UsageDailyUnusedSlots` WHERE Date >= '$Today' AND RotaType LIKE '%Derm%' AND UnusedSlots > 0 AND RotaType NOT LIKE '%- Y%' AND RotaType NOT LIKE '%- y%' ORDER BY Date LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2;";
```

however this would find me the 3rd day with available slots, not the 3rd slot.

I could do a complicated loop of each row, adding up the value with each iteration/loop and echoing the value when the total >= 3, however I feel there must be a better way.

Here is a scenario

[image: Table of Data]

My sql code above would select 31/01/2020 as the 3rd day with UnusedSlots on, however I want it to select 30/01/2020 as the date as that's when the 3rd next unused appointment is

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What do YOU mean by "3d available appointment"?

Comment: What is RotaType? What type column and also what does it mean in your data?

Comment: What version of mysql are you on.

Comment: sample scenario added above for clarity... actually running MariaDB 10.3

Comment: Does `RotaType` collation is case-sensitive?

Comment: Yes case sensitive @Akina

Comment: Please provide a fiddle, or at least CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO textual scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           SUM(UnusedSlots) OVER (ORDER BY Date) cnt
    FROM `UsageDailyUnusedSlots` 
    WHERE Date >= '$Today' 
    AND RotaType LIKE '%Derm%' 
    AND UnusedSlots > 0 
    AND RotaType NOT LIKE '%- Y%' 
    AND RotaType NOT LIKE '%- y%' )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cnt >= 3
ORDER BY cnt
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows functions to find the specific location of the slot you want. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select
    *,
    sum(`UnusedSlots`) over(order by Date 
      rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as previous_slots,
    sum(`UnusedSlots`) over(order by Date) as current_slots
  from `UsageDailyUnusedSlots`
  where Date >= '2020-01-15' 
    and RotaType like '%Derm%' 
    and RotaType not like '%- Y%' 
) x
where previous_slots < 3 and current_slots >= 3
```

Comment: this doesn't quite look like it does the required, although it's along the right lines I feel

Comment: @HenryAspden It works as expected. See SQLFiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bqteJ2PN2UgzUD8ceXn4Gx/0